# Meteor easy search and iron-router

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteorite

I'm using this easy serach for my project https://github.com/matteodem/meteor-easy-search

my search Index

```
EasySearch.createSearchIndex('searchIndex', {
  'collection'    : blog,              
  'field'         : ['title', 'tags'],    
  'limit'         : 20,                  
    "use":"mongo-db",
  'query' : function (searchString) {
        // Default query that will be used for searching
        var query = EasySearch.getSearcher(this.use).defaultQuery(this, searchString);
        return query;
    }
});
```

and now I have search box and when User enters something and click on enter I want to route to search page

```
this.route("search",{
      path:'/search/:slug',
      waitOn:function(){
            //here I want the search data to be sent to search page
            var query=this.params.slug;
          EasySearch.search('searchIndex', query, function (err, data) {
              console.log(data);
        });
      },
      data:function(){

      }
    });
```

In this router I want the searchIndex data to be sent to search page, how to do this

my click event

```
'submit .search':function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var quer=$("#query").val();
    // Router.go('search');
    }
```

**UPDATE**

My main question is in the router waiton function how we get the data in callback and send it to the search page?

Comment: You would have to use the component API for a call back. Theres brief examples listed, go for "retrieve component values" + "searching with component values". Those are what you would require. Its built in so you dont need to build from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

In your click event handler, you have commented out the line: Router.go('search').

If you write

> Router.go('search', {slug: quer})

That would route you to the search page with the query data collected from the page, if that is what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the response, my real problem is not with that, checkout the updated question

Comment: I haven't used EasySearch, but I have a guess. waitOn is usually used to wait for data subscriptions. Inside the data function is where you might want to call: EasySearch.search...